# How to load data which is used by the entire AngularJs Application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb, angular-controller

In my application there is some data which is used by other controllers to do their job.

So for example I need the user and some other entities to do REST calls to the server.

At the moment I have an AppController `(app.js)` which loads basic data which will be used by controllers of all `ng-views (see index.html).`
The functions `loadUser() and loadRequiredEntity()` store values received from REST-Calls in `indexedDb`.

Any controller of ng-views which are displayed `(see ng-view in index.html)` read the loaded data from `indexedDb`.

I think there are some mayor problems with this approach:

- Does AppController load all Data before controllers of ng-view try to access them?
- `loadUser() and loadRequiredEntity()` call services (for example userService) which execute rest-calls and return promises so AppController is finished before the entire data was loaded, right? So the controllers of ng-views begin to read from indexedDb before any value is stored there.

How do I load basic data which is required to be there for use by other controllers?
Is an AngularJs controller the right choice?

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app" id="appBody" ng-controller="AppController as appCtrl">
    <md-content id="content" ng-view=""></md-content>
</body>
```

app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
module app {
      export class AppController {

          static $inject = ['$log'];

          private _LOG_PREFIX : string = 'AppController: ';

          constructor(private $log: ng.ILogService) {
          this.$log.info(this._LOG_PREFIX + 'started');
          this.loadUser()
          .then(this.loadRequiredEntity)
          .then(this.markAsAuthenticated, this.handleLoadBasedataError);
          }
          ...
      }
}
```

Comment: The right choice is there but it's primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Melou mentioned ui-router solves the problem.

The basic data is loaded in an abstract state.

```
module app.core {
    "use strict";
    import LoadBasicDataService = app.core.services.LoadBasicDataService;

    function loadBasicDataForControllers(loadBasicDataService: LoadBasicDataService) : ng.IPromise<any> {
        return loadBasicDataService.load();
    }
    loadBasicDataForControllers.$inject = ['loadBasicDataService'];

    function configureCore($urlRouterProvider: angular.ui.IUrlRouterProvider, $stateProvider: angular.ui.IStateProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/myComponent1");        

    $stateProvider
        .state("main",{
           templateUrl: "layout/main.html",
           abstract: true,
           resolve: {
               'loadBasicDataForController': loadBasicDataForControllers
           }
        })
        .state("main.myComponent2",{
           url: "/myComponent2",
           template: "<myComponent2></myComponent2>"
        })
        .state("main.myComponent1",{
           url: "/myComponent1",
           template: "<myComponent1></myComponent1>"
        });
    }
    configureCore.$inject = ["$urlRouterProvider", "$stateProvider"];

    angular
    .module("app.core")
    .config(configureCore);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Accessing data:**
You should store your data in a service, eg `UserService`. `$http` calls should be made from services only. This is opinion based, but shared by many, see for example [this really popular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

**Loading data before loading controllers:** In your router configuration you can define a `resolve` option (available in angular default router and ui-router). Use this `resolve` option to load data before accessing pages of your app. see in [ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) or in [default router](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

1. In resolve, `call userService.load()`
2. In each controller, you can then access the data, eg: `userService.getUsers()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Accessing data: I already do it like you suggested. Loading data before loading controllers: I will try to implement the resolve option in my router. I suppose that if AppController is not loaded no other controller will be loaded before AppController. So that may work. I will try it...

Comment: For all components loaded by the router it works to use resolve to load the data. But for components like my top navigation bar it does not work. Any suggestions? Maybe run load functionality in a run-block?

Comment: With ui-router you can declare parent/child routes. Your "main" route coud load data and contain your toolbar. Then all your other route can have main as their parent route, eg: "main.subroute1", "main.subroute2"...

A runblock is another candidate.